# Using CDATA in Android Strings file

Tags: android, localization

I found nothing about CDATA in the Android Developers documentation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

I was wondering if I need to escape any characters inside CDATA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should escape ' characters. Quotes are fine, though. Here's a sample:

```
<string name="info_prefix"><DATA><![CDATA[<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><style type=\'text/css\'>body { font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica; font-size:small; color:#333333 } b { color:#00468C }</style></head><body>]]></DATA></string>
```